# cd root access denied

Tags: permissions, root

I have set up my root password but when I try and cd to root dir I get:

```
bash: cd: root: Permission denied
```

the exact command is:

cd root

sorry I was unclear but the issue is resolved now thanks a lot everyone.=D

Comment: You forgot to post the actual command. Looks like there is a mistake there.

Comment: Why did you set a root password ? use `sudo -i` See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo / Also it is likely `cd /root`

Comment: did you use "cd root /path/? if you did you should use "sudo cd /path/

Comment: @sbergeron that won't work because `cd` is a shell built-in

Comment: What is the exact command?

Comment: I'm not sure what he even did

Comment: the excact command was cd root

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best thing to do is `sudo su` or `su`, then cd to /root. You can (if you want) string together commands like this: `su -c "cd /root; dostuff"`, but the first way is easier if you need to get into /root.

Comment: just make sure to type exit in the shell right after you do that, as it is then completely root and any further commands could REALLY mess up your system

Comment: I am getting following error : " su: must be run from a terminal"

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Create a new question with your situation and problem. This question is 2 years old.